# Css not loading in my VPS for magento 2

Tags: php, css, magento, vps, magento2

Cleared cache,
Given 777 permission to all files and folder in maganto directory,
still no solution..

I can't even access the admin panel, because links don't work properly.

This was a fresh install, I did

```
git clone magento_https_link
```

where link is the github link for magento2 @ github.

Everything went out well, I followed the official tutorial, installed composer thing and all, I installed it, followed steps to the end, and when installation was complete, I clicked on frontend and no css, and backend, no css.
Css was working fine during installation.

When I press F12 and switch to console, it says error 404 on css , javascript , and image files. And if I try to visit the url manually for any css they are not there. Its really weird.

And I don't know what is css js merge. No idea about this.

My core config in database:

```
mysql> select * from `core_config_data`;
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                          | value                                    |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|         1 | default |        0 | web/seo/use_rewrites          | 1                                        |
|         2 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url         | http://NAME_OF_SITE/magento/magento2/  |
|         3 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url           | https://NAME_OF_SITE/magento/magento2/ |
|         4 | default |        0 | general/locale/code           | en_US                                    |
|         5 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_frontend    | NULL                                     |
|         6 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_adminhtml   | NULL                                     |
|         7 | default |        0 | general/locale/timezone       | XX/XX                             |
|         8 | default |        0 | currency/options/base         | XX                                      |
|         9 | default |        0 | currency/options/default      | XX                                      |
|        10 | default |        0 | currency/options/allow        | XX                                      |
|        11 | default |        0 | general/region/display_all    | 1                                        |
|        12 | default |        0 | general/region/state_required | AT,BR,CA,CH,DE,EE,ES,FI,FR,LT,LV,RO,US   |
|        13 | default |        0 | catalog/category/root_id      | NULL                                     |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hello, does index.php runs currently can you put a die() function to cross check ?

Comment: yes it runs.
Anyways I was using the git clone thing, instead of that I downloaded from official website of magento and upload, it worked perfectly, there is something wrong with git version..

Answer (score 3):

did you execute all the needed steps using the bin/magento installer ?

It sounds like you should try to do(in your root magento category):

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 have this initial issue, but follow below steps for getting its work !

Step 1 : Run CMD 
Step 2 : Goto Magento installation directory using

> CD wamp/www/[Magento dir.]

Step 3 : Run

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Step 4 : Run

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Step 5 : Delete Cache from

> var/cache/[delete all dir.]

It's getting work for Front-end & Back-end !

http://developerforums.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Magento2 Css-Js-images-loading issues :**

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scipts-and-css/64808#64808

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48256/magento-2-installation-css-js-images-not-loading

Answer (score 0):

Just open `MAGENTO_ROOT/app/etc/di.xml` and replace below code from line number 574

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

to

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```